# PHP DOM Get all a hrefs from page and remove duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, dom

I am creating a script that gets all links from an website and checking every link if is broken. My problem is, I need to display all links founded but I need to verify only the unique links not the duplicate. For example if a website has 4 links to google.com then I want to check only one time not four times.

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {

$info = $node->getAttribute( 'href' );

///The function that checks for broken links working. 
$check_url_status = check_url($info);

if ($check_url_status == '404') {

$badresult = 'Not working';

}else{

$badresult = 'Working';

}

$showlist .= '<li>The '.$info.' is '.$badresult.'</li>';

}


echo '<ul>'.$showlist.'</ul>';
```

This code is works, but I need to make it check the http status only 1 time for duplicate links.

I do not have idea of how to do this and also if is posible to do something like that.

Comment: Make an array and then check every time before checking the status if the link is already in the array, if not check link and add array to link, if it exists skip link.

Comment: Can you show me an example code? I really stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an array which you can use to save all already checked links in it. You will always check before checking the status if the link is already in the array or not. If so, skip link. If not, check status and add link to the array. You can skip an element by using the keyword `continue`.

```
$links = array();
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    $info = $node->getAttribute('href');

    if(!isset($links[$info])) {
        ///The function that checks for broken links working.
        $check_url_status = check_url($info);
        $links[$info] = $check_url_status;
    } else {
        $check_url_status = $links[$info];
    }

    if ($check_url_status == '404') {
        $badresult = 'Not working';
    } else {
        $badresult = 'Working';
    }

    $showlist .= '<li>The '.$info.' is '.$badresult.'</li>';
}

echo '<ul>'.$showlist.'</ul>';
```

Comment: Sorry actually not working for what I need, because it also replaces all links. I need to be something like this:  `The google.com is Working, The google.com is Working, The google.com is Working` but to check only 1 time the google.com and display it 3 times if the link is 3 times inside the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArray       = array();
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    $info               = $node->getAttribute('href');
    if(!in_array($info, $newArray)) {
        $newArray[]         = $info;
        $check_url_status   = check_url($info);
        $badresult          = ($check_url_status == '404') ? 'Not working' : "Working"
        $showlist .= '<li>The '.$info.' is '.$badresult.'</li>';
    }
}
```

you can initiate an array, and push the values into it, whenever it enters into the condition, which means `if the hrefValue is not available into the array`.